# Using sed to replace single quotes between two characters

Tags: sed

I have a string like this:

```
'abc','D'art','abc'
```

Using sed I can replace `D'a` for '`D\'a'` using:

```
sed -i "s/D'a/D\\\'a/g" file1.sql
```

The problem is that I have a huge SQL file, and every step of the way I have a new combination (D'A, T'b, P'a...)...
So I am looking for an effective way of detecting single quotes in between letters so I can escape them.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice you may want to escape every single-quote adjacent to not-a-comma from both sides.

> and every step of the way I have a new combination (D'A, T'b, P'a...)

You don't need to cover each combination separately. Backreferences of the form `\1`, `\2` are useful here:

```
sed "s/\([^,]\)'\([^,]\)/\1\\\'\2/g"
#      ^^^^^^^^                       The 1st capture group (it matches not-a-comma)...
#                        ^^           ... is referenced here by \1.
#               ^^^^^^^^              And the 2nd one...
#                              ^^     ... is referenced here by \2.
```

Comment: for some reason it is not replacing the text, but printing it.... any clue why?

Comment: @Walucas Because I omitted `-i` to make the answer more general; and to avoid making permanent changes in case it was wrong. I admit I assumed you know what `-i` does, since *you* used it in the first place.

Comment: its one of my first times using `sed`, but I did try with `-i` but it failed somehow....

Comment: @Walucas Very basic question: did you give the command a file to operate on?

Comment: hehehe, yes I did :)